# Group by count and first use together in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am using

```
df_topics = df.groupby(['string1','theme']).count().reset_index().first()
```

giving me this error

```
TypeError: first() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'
```

I simply want to count the duplicates by group by and want to select Non NULL first row

 It is why i am using first(). Which gives me non null first row.

dataframe

```
string1      theme      type    tool    site 
houses       white      A       phone           
houses       black      B               cloud
houses       white      A               web
houses       white      A       phone   web
```

output

```
string1      theme      Type    tool    site   count
houses       white      A       phone   web    3
houses       black      B               cloud  1
```

My main focus is counting string1 but with that i also want to select row to shown in final output is the one who have lesser non null value.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create dictionary of columns without `string1` with `first` function and add `count` for `string1`, pass to [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and last rename column:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['string1','theme']), 'first')
d['string1'] = 'count'
df_topics = (df.groupby(['string1','theme'], sort=False)
               .agg(d)
               .rename(columns={'string1':'count'})
               .reset_index())
print (df_topics)

  string1  theme   site   tool type  count
0  houses  white    web  phone    A      3
1  houses  black  cloud    NaN    B      1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (d)
{'site': 'first', 'tool': 'first', 'type': 'first', 'string1': 'count'}
```

Or use named aggregations:

```
df_topics = (df.groupby(['string1','theme'], sort=False)
              .agg(type=('type','first'),
                   tool=('tool','first'),
                   site=('site', 'first'),
                   count=('string1','count'))
              .reset_index())
print (df_topics)
  string1  theme type   tool   site  count
0  houses  white    A  phone    web      3
1  houses  black    B    NaN  cloud      1
```

What is same like generate values dynamically:

```
d = {x: (x, 'first') for x in df.columns.difference(['string1','theme'])}
d['count'] = ('string1','count')


df_topics = (df.groupby(['string1','theme'], sort=False)
               .agg(**d)
               .reset_index())
print (df_topics)
  string1  theme   site   tool type  count
0  houses  white    web  phone    A      3
1  houses  black  cloud    NaN    B      1
```

EDIT1:

```
g = df.groupby(['string1','theme'], sort=False)
df1 = g.size()
df_topics = g.first()

df_topics = pd.concat([df_topics, df1.rename("count")], axis=1, sort=False).reset_index() 
print (df_topics)
  string1  theme type   tool   site  count
0  houses  white    A  phone    web      3
1  houses  black    B    NaN  cloud      1
```

Comment: in short, i have to do it separately. there is not way to do it together.

Comment: @lil-wolf - Like need in question it is not possible, need [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) here for working with different functions like `first`  and `count` together

Comment: Hi, i found another solution.
<br> df1 = df.groupby(['string1','theme']).size().reset_index(name="count")
<br> df_topics = df.groupby(['string1','theme']).first().reset_index()
<br> df_topics = pd.concat([df_topics, df1['count']], axis=1)
<br> what do u think , will it work ?
<br> size() and count() is i guess fine for me as size() also includes NaN
<br> Im thinking about reset_index() and concat() . Will it sort in same order each time and concat with right row or what?

Comment: @lil-wolf - If same groupby definition are used for each `size` and `count` then output is same, `pd.concat` sometimes sorting column, you can prevent it by `sort=False`, added to answer.